# Optional ride destination (end_latitude and end_longitude or end_place_id) while requesting a ride via uber api

Tags: uber-api

Currently, the documentation for request endpoint (https://developer.uber.com/docs/v1-requests) states that

> ... Either this or end_latitude and end_longitude may be specified.

for the *end_place_id* parameter. Similarly, it states that in the absence of either *end_latitude* or *end_longitude*, *end_place_id* must be provided.

Uber's app allows users to book a cab without a destination; is it possible to use the uber API to do the same? After testing, I've seen that it is possible to successfully book a cab without destination in sandbox mode.

Are such requests allowed/successful in production as well? If so, is there an end-point through which we can allow users to update their destination after booking? I could not find any such end-point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating a request the minimum parameter you need is access_token (in Authorisation Header) and either of (start_latitude , start_longitude) or start_place_id. This works even on production.

You can use this API https://developer.uber.com/docs/v1-requests-patch to update destination.